# Use the jvm cacerts or own truststore when using selfsigned x.509 certificate

Tags: java, security, ssl, jvm, truststore

i'm using a selfsigned x.509 certificate to encrypt a client-/server communication. I'm wondering if importing the self-signed certificate into the clients jvm cacerts truststore causes any security issues. Is it more secure to create and use my own truststore for this or doesn't it matter which way i prefer? Why there is a usecase to create (and use) own truststores, when i always have the possibility to import my (selfsigned) cert into the jvms truststore?

Comment: It mainly causes the security issue that if the JVM gets updated by the client you're out of business. Don't do this.